# How to print an array using a function?

Tags: arrays, c

Could anyone help explain why my code doesn't work? I want to print an array by passing the whole array into a function as its parameters.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printArray(int *array);

int main(void)
{
    int array[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

    printArray(array);

}

void printArray(int *array)
{
    int sizeArr = sizeof(*array) / sizeof(int);

    for (int i = 0; i < sizeArr; i++)
    {
        printf("%i ", array[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: sizeof(*array) is 4 and sizeof(int) is also 4 so sizeArr = 1, The Loop will only run once and print the first element.

Comment: The `array` in the function, i.e. `int *array` is fundamentally just a reference to the first element in the array. There is no information about the length of the array. Hence you either need to pass that information as an additional parameter or encode it into the array (e.g. by terminating with a special value, just like a C string is terminated with 0).

Comment: You're not passing an array: you're passing a pointer. Note that even `void printArray(int array[])` gets passed a pointer. *The only way to pass arrays around is to embed them inside a struct and pass the struct around (but don't to this).*

Answer (score 2):

Your parameter has changed from an array to a pointer, so `sizeof(*array) / sizeof(int)` is always 1. You need to change the function definition to like below:

```
void printArray(int *array, int len)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        printf("%i ", array[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Don't advertise your app here.

Answer (score -1):

Copy-paste this.

```
#include <stdio.h>

void printArray(int *array);

int main(void)
{
    int array[] = {0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6};

    printArray(array);

}

void printArray(int *array, int len)
{
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++)
    {
        printf("%i ", array[i]);
    }

    printf("\n");
}
}
```